# Unable to enable Future Parser in puppet.conf

Tags: puppetmaster, puppet-agent

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Enable future parser as described in [this documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/experiments_future.html#enabling-the-future-parser)

*/etc/puppet/puppet.conf*

```
[main]
parser = future
```

2. Add lambda code to a pp file

*site.pp*

```
$systems = [
  'system01',
  'system02',
  'system03',
  'system04',
  'system05',
  'system06',
  'system07',
  'system08',
  'system09',
  'system10'
]

each($systems) |$value| { notify $value }
```

3. Run puppet

**Outcome**

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: 
Could not parse for environment production: This Name is not productive. 
A non productive construct may only be placed last in a block/sequence at 
/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:38:27 on node vm-one.domain
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

**Attempts to solve issue**

1. Googling neither `Could not parse for environment production: This Name is not productive` nor `A non productive construct may only be placed last in a block/sequence` resulted in an answer that solves the issue.
2. Moving `each($systems) |$value| { notify $value }` to the end of the file did not solve the issue either

Comment: Unsure if this is the real problem, but that shouldn't be `notify`. It should be `notice`.

Comment: Which line is it referencing?  Did you make the config change to enable the future parser on the master as well as the agent node?  Did you restart the services after you made the change?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Implementing it in the [agent] section and restarting the services did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after changing `each($systems) |$value| { notify $value }` to `each($systems) |$value| { notify {$value:} }`: